When I deploy my app in docker throws me an error creating the Bean
I am new using docker and I am trying to create an image using docker build and finally the image is create successfully. But when I try to run the image throws me the next error. Someone could help me to understand what is happening with my app. (When I run the app in local I don't hace any problem, even executing the jar everything is ok) the problem is only in docker. The database is a keyspace in aws, additional I have another error I supposed is with the connection.
This is my Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-buster AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY build.gradle settings.gradle gradlew /app/
COPY gradle /app/gradle

COPY src /app/src

RUN chmod +x gradlew

RUN ./gradlew build --no-daemon --info

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/build/libs/*.jar /app/application.jar
COPY --from=build /app/build/resources/main/cassandra_truststore.jks /app/cassandra_truststore.jks

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseContainerSupport", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app/application.jar"]

This is my Interface
public interface VisitorsRepository extends CassandraRepository<VisitorEntity, String> {}

this is my service, I created the bean manually so I don't need @Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class VisitorService {

@Autowired
private VisitorsRepository repository;

public ApiResponse execute(VisitorDto dto){
    return Mono.just(repository.save(VisitorMapper.dtoToEntity(dto)))
            .map(visitorEntity ->
                            ResponseMapper.buildResponse(true, HttpStatus.CREATED.value(), HttpStatus.CREATED.getReasonPhrase(),     HttpStatus.CREATED.value(), HttpStatus.CREATED.getReasonPhrase())
                    )
            .doOnSuccess(m -> log.info("entity saved"))
            .doOnError(error -> log.error("Error saving entity: " + error.getMessage()))
            .onErrorResume(error -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException(error.getMessage()))).block();
}
}

this is the @Bean
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public VisitorService getVisitorService(){
     return new VisitorService();
  }
}

this is my controller
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Validated
@Slf4j
public class VisitorController {

   private final VisitorService service;

   @PostMapping("/create-visitor")
   public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> execute(@RequestBody @Valid VisitorDto dto){
      try{
          ApiResponse apiResponse = service.execute(dto);
          return new ResponseEntity<ApiResponse>(apiResponse,HttpStatus.OK);
      }catch (Exception e){
          e.getStackTrace();
          throw new BadRequestException(e.getMessage());
   }

  }
}

And this is the error

ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'visitorController' defined in URL
[jar:nested:/app/application.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/ipservice/controller/VisitorController.class]:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0:
Error creating bean with name 'getVisitorService': Unsatisfied
dependency expressed through field 'repository': Error creating bean
with name 'visitorsRepository' defined in
ipservice.repository.VisitorsRepository defined in
@EnableCassandraRepositories declared on CassandraConfig: Cannot
resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean
property 'cassandraTemplate'
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing
implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class:
sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
ipservice.configuration.CassandraConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.session()
~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.security.KeyManagementException: problem accessing
trust store

application.yml configuration
cloud:
  aws:
   stack:
    auto: false
   region:
    static: "us-east-1"
   cassandra:
    username: "cassandra-user-at-466964128512"
    password: "XXXXXXXXX"
    trustStoreUrl: "./src/main/resources/cassandra_truststore.jks"
    trustStorePassword: "XXXXXXX"
    keySpace: "comparaasegurate"
    localDatacenter: "us-east-1"
    resolveContactPoints: true
    contactPoints: "cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9142"
    requestPageSize: 3500
    requestTimeout: 3
    requestConsistency: "LOCAL_QUORUM"
    reconnectOnInit: true
    sssEngineFactoryClass: "DefaultSslEngineFactory"
    sslHostnameValidation: true


What is the actual location of your truststore, looks like you aren't copying it properly (and I also wonder why you have a specific Cassandra Config and not just the auto-config one).

Hi, the actual location is:
cloud:
aws:
stack:
auto: false
region:
static: "us-east-1"
cassandra:
username: "cassandra-user-at-466964128512"
password: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
trustStoreUrl: "./src/main/resources/cassandra_truststore.jks"
trustStorePassword: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
keySpace: "comparaasegurate"
localDatacenter: "us-east-1"
resolveContactPoints: true
contactPoints: "cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9142"
requestPageSize: 3500
This is a part  of my application.yml

src/main/resources doesn't exist after the code is compiled and packaged into the jar. You'll want to try classpath:// prefix. Or /app/cassandra_truststore.jks

I don't want the "actual" location but thelocation in your source tree, and please don't post configuration/code as comments as that is totally unreadable. Edit your question instead and use proper formatting when doing so.

I just upload the configuration/code in the post thanks for your recommendation, in my Dockerfile im trying to copy from this route
COPY --from=build /app/build/resources/main/cassandra_truststore.jks /app/cassandra_truststore.jks

@OneCricketeer How should I modify my Dockerfile?

I didn't say to modify the Dockerfile. I said to change application.yml to use a valid path to the trustStoreUrl, such as /app/cassandra_truststore.jks, which is where you'd copied it
